# Rails Heroku production GraphiQL "__schema field requires authentication" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, graphql, graphiql

GraphiQL is working on local development, however when I deploy it to Heroku I get an error below. It cannot fetch schema and docs, however I can run queries without problems and get response. Any ideas what could be the issue?

[GraphiQL IDE error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6rgd.png)